# How to combine texture nodes?

Tags: texturing, node-editor, shader-nodes

I've been trying to combine these two textures so there is black background with white elements from both of them. I tried different mix rgb node variants but nothing seems to work. Changing the factor in mix RGB shows one texture or the other, but not both at the same time.
Please help

Texture 1:
[image: texture 1]

Texture 2:
[image: texture 2]

Node set up:
[image: nodes]

Result:
[image: result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *MixRGB / Lighten* mode with the factor at 1 seems to work:

[image]