# How can I plug multiple image texture nodes into the base color?

Tags: texturing, node-editor, shaders, shader-nodes

I'm trying to put two different kinds of scratches on my mesh, but I'm not sure how am I able to mix the two image texture nodes into the base color. How can I do that?
[image: Screenshot]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, you haven't packed your images so we can't see them, also maybe tell what kind of mix you want? You probably can do it with the MixRGB...

Comment: Hello, @moonboots. I'm sorry I couldn't upload the .blend file with the resources it exceeded the maximum upload size. I want to mix the two scratches together. Basically have two kinds of scratches on my mesh. I don't know what mixing methods should I approach. I'm pretty new to the nodes and texturing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should try the Color > MixRGB, it has several modes, the correct mode will depend on the scratch images and how you want to mix them. To share your file you can use workupload.com for example

Comment: @moonboots I've packed the images and uploaded them on workupload.com. Would you please take a look? Thank you. https://workupload.com/file/WrXTVtSGPDC

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to combine texture nodes?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/219119/how-to-combine-texture-nodes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you could mix your 2 textures with a *Color > MixRGB* in *Lighten* mode and push the factor up to 1:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, moonboots! I really appreciate your help!